# Issues with running and returning two functions at the same time

Tags: python

I am not entirely sure what is wrong with my program, I am trying to return both `get_paint_info` and `calc_paint_area`, but the output is either the first function or the second one. Is there anything wrong?

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
from ipywidgets import interact
display(HTML("<h1>House <font color='blue'>Depot Paint</font> Estimator</h1>"))
@interact_manual(length=(1,40,1),width =(1,40,1), height = (6,10,0.5), coats=(1,3,1), paint=['Everyday','Premium', 'Professional'])
def calc_paint_area(length, width, height, coats, paint):
    area = (2 * length + 2 * width) * height
    area = area * coats
    return(area)
    def get_paint_info(paint):
        if  paint == 'Everyday':
            cost = 19.95
            coverage = 320
        elif paint == 'Premium':
            cost = 29.95
            coverage = 400
        elif paint == 'Professional':
            cost = 34.95
            coverage = 425
        return (cost, coverage)
    val1, val2 = get_paint_info(paint)
    print(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Is `def get_paint_info` really supposed to be indented inside `def calc_paint_area`

Comment: You should first try to move `get_paint_info()` outside and just *call* it from within `calc_paint_area()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "return two functions"? Do you mean return the values from calling both functions, or return references to both functions?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the response, when I run this program, either the value from calc_paint_area shows up or if I swap the place of the functions, get_paint_info shows up, I can't make both of them appear in a consequent manner.

Comment: @quamrana Hi, thanks for your response, I am not entirely sure what this means, could you please elaborate? Sorry if this is a stupid question I am pretty new to python.

Comment: Well, I can show you what it means to move one function outside the other, but I still don't know how you want to return the values from both functions. Did you mean `return area,val1,val2`?

Comment: Show your example code where you try to call both functions and only one is showing up.

Comment: And please fix the indentation.

Comment: (@Barmar: I see no indentation problems)

Comment: @Barmar If I'm not mistaken, this is the example code. In a Jupyter notebook, [`interact_manual`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#interact_manual) automagically makes a graphical widget with which the user can select the input and see the output of the function. (I really should try this notebook thing out eventually, it sounds cool.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets executed after a `return` statement. You need to put the nested function before that, then return everything at the end.

```
def calc_paint_area(length, width, height, coats, paint):
    area = (2 * length + 2 * width) * height
    area = area * coats

    def get_paint_info(paint):
        if  paint == 'Everyday':
            cost = 19.95
            coverage = 320
        elif paint == 'Premium':
            cost = 29.95
            coverage = 400
        elif paint == 'Professional':
            cost = 34.95
            coverage = 425
        return (cost, coverage)

    val1, val2 = get_paint_info(paint)
    print(val1, val2)

    return(val1, val2, area)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons to define one function inside another, but more often than not it's for somewhat advanced things like dynamically building functions, writing your own decorators, and such. For general use, you usually want to define them separately. You could do something like this:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact_manual

@interact_manual(length=(1,40,1), width=(1,40,1), height=(6,10,0.5), coats=(1,3,1))
def calc_paint_area(length, width, height, coats, paint):
    area = (2 * length + 2 * width) * height
    area = area * coats
    return area

@interact_manual(paint=['Everyday', 'Premium', 'Professional'])
def get_paint_info(paint):
    if paint == 'Everyday':
        cost = 19.95
        coverage = 320
    elif paint == 'Premium':
        cost = 29.95
        coverage = 400
    elif paint == 'Professional':
        cost = 34.95
        coverage = 425
    return cost, coverage
```

Or if you definitely want it all accessed through one function, you can call one function from inside the other. (If doing so, I would rename the function doing the calling, to reflect all of what it's returning.)

```py
from ipywidgets import interact_manual

@interact_manual(length=(1,40,1), width=(1,40,1), height=(6,10,0.5),
                 coats=(1,3,1), paint=['Everyday', 'Premium', 'Professional'])
def get_paint_area_and_info(length, width, height, coats, paint):
    area = (2 * length + 2 * width) * height
    area = area * coats
    cost, coverage = get_paint_info(paint)
    return area, cost, coverage

def get_paint_info(paint):
    if paint == 'Everyday':
        cost = 19.95
        coverage = 320
    elif paint == 'Premium':
        cost = 29.95
        coverage = 400
    elif paint == 'Professional':
        cost = 34.95
        coverage = 425
    return cost, coverage
```